src/main/java not visible in Eclipse after importing gradle project
I try to import a simple springboot helloworld project into Eclipse. The project will have a large number dependencies to other projects, local jars and web repos, so I have added a sourceSets definition to build.gradle to be able to debug and modify code where ever I need.
The project builds and runs without a hitch from the commandline with 'gradle bootRun'.
In Eclipse When I do "Import... / Gradle / Existing Gradle project" the resulting Eclipse package view is missing the 'src/main/java'.
It looks like anything that references a sub directory of where the gradle.build is is ignored by Eclipse.
Eclipse picks the first sourceSets reference that is not a sub directory, turns that into a 'src' folder and all the rest references in the sourceSets into source folders with the reference name with -src appended.
I cannot show the screen shot but it looks like this in package explorer:
MyProject
 >src
   [contents of FooProjectA]
 >FooProjectB-src
 >FooProjectC-src
etc etc 

I've tried umpteen different things and nothing works.
As soon as I add my sourceFileSets it all goes south.
It looks like all sourceSets
Here is my (obfuscated) build.gradle as it is atm.
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


group = 'com.myproject'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

compileJava.options.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
compileJava.options.warnings = false


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}  

sourceSets {
    main {
        java{
            srcDirs = [
            src/main/java',
            '../FooProjectA/src',
            '../FooProjectB/src', 
            '../FooProjectC/src', 
[SNIP more of the same]
            ]
        }
    }
}

configurations {
   all*.exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
   all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-classic'
   all*.exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module: 'logback-core'
}


dependencies {
    implementation files (
        '../jar_lib/libjar1.jar',
        '../jar_lib/libjar2.jar',
        '../jar_lib/libjar3.jar',
[SNIP more of the same]
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web' 
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.20.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.20.0'
    
}


test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}



I have the following setup:
Eclipse EE 2024-09
-Spring Tools 4 plugin
-Buildship 3 pluging
EDIT
I tried to open the project with IntelliJ and it opened project without a problem and I was able to run and debug my code and dependent projects without a hitch.
So my conclusion is that my project build.gradle is correct but that gradle eclipse pluging that generates the Eclipse project files is buggy and hence it is no possible to use Eclipse for this project. Likewise I tried Visual Studio Code and while that opened the project correctly the compile fails so I cannot run and debug my code in VSC :( :(
EDIT
My settings.gradle has only one line
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'


What does your settings.gradle look like? This is where you should specify which directories/modules are part of your gradle project

@RobEvans My settings.gradle has only one line
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'

For each subfolder/module add a line entry include 'subfolder_name'. If eclipse understands the gradle project structure it should then pick up on the individual modules by these entries

The source paths ../FooProjectA/src, ../FooProjectB/src, ... are outside of your Eclipse project and have to be included as linked folders. Each of these folders is assigned a name:
../FooProjectB/src => FooProjectB-src
../FooProjectC/src => FooProjectC-src
[...]

Unfortunately the folder ../FooProjectA/src is assigned the name src:
../FooProjectA/src => src

This name is in conflict with the existing physical file location src/main/java. As a workaround to this bug you can change the assigned name for ../FooProjectA/src. This have to be done in two places:

The name of the linked folder in the project
The source path entry in the classpath

Please add these lines to your build.gradle:
eclipse {
    project {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                it.linkedResources.find { it.name == 'src' }.name = 'FooProjectA-src'
            }
        }
    }
    classpath {
        file {
            whenMerged {
                it.entries.find { it.path == 'src' }.path = 'FooProjectA-src'
            }
        }
    }
}

After invoking Refresh Gradle Project your source folders should be configured correctly.
